# Upload Array of Images to the server in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, image-uploading

I have to use a custom Multiple Images selection third party folder in my project for the selection of images and these images are coming in an array. The link for custom images selection is this [CreolePhotoSelection.](https://github.com/NirmalsinhRathod/CreolePhotoSelection)

Now I'm trying to upload the array of images to the service , but it is giving me this error:

> -[__NSDictionaryM CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800024dce0
>       2017-07-31 12:41:46.777 PK.House[7795:1224040] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSDictionaryM CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x60800024dce0'

**My code for uploading images is,**

```
-(void)submit
    {

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
        NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
        NSLog(@"\n"
              "theDate: |%@| ", theDate);

       UIImage *image = [self.arrImages objectAtIndex:imagecount];
       imagecount++;


        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7f)];
        NSLog(@"Data is %@",imageData);

        NSString *baseurl = @"My URL";

        NSURL *dataURL = [NSURL URLWithString:baseurl];

        NSMutableURLRequest *dataRqst = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:dataURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];

        [dataRqst setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
        NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];

        [dataRqst addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];


        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",theDate]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:imageData];
        [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [dataRqst setHTTPBody:postBody];

        NSHTTPURLResponse* response =[[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Response is %@",response);
        NSError* error = nil ;
         NSLog(@"Error is %@",error);
        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:dataRqst delegate:self];
         NSLog(@"Connection is %@",conn);
    }

    #pragma mark NSURLConnection Delegate Methods

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

        self.receiveData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

        [self.receiveData appendData:data];


        NSError* error;

        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data

                                                             options:kNilOptions

                                                               error:&error];
        NSLog(@"json..%@",json);

        if (imagecount <[self.arrImages count]) {

           [self submit];
        }

       else
    {

            UIAlertView *alert=  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                           message:@"Data uploaded successfully"
                                                          delegate:nil

                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil

                                                otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] ;
            [alert show];
        }

    }

    - (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                      willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {

        return nil;
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    }

    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:

    (NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten 

    totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
    {

    }
```

My selection Images code is this:

```
    - (IBAction)Select:(id)sender 
    {
    CreolePhotoSelection *objCreolePhotoSelection= [[CreolePhotoSelection alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreolePhotoSelection" bundle:nil];
    objCreolePhotoSelection.strTitle = @"Images";
    objCreolePhotoSelection.delegate = self; // It will help to retrive all selected photos from CreolePhotoSelection
    objCreolePhotoSelection.arySelectedPhoto = _arrImages; // You need to pass same array which is holding selected image
    objCreolePhotoSelection.maxCount = 50; // Eg. 5, 10 anythings...

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objCreolePhotoSelection];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

And the Functions are these:

```
    -(void)getSelectedPhoto:(NSMutableArray *)aryPhoto

{
    //    //Initlize array

    //    NSArray *aryAlImage = [aryPhoto valueForKeyPath:@"mainImage"];

    //

    //    NSMutableArray *ary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:aryAlImage];

    _arrImages = nil;

    _arrImages = [NSMutableArray new];

    _arrImages = [aryPhoto mutableCopy]; //mainImage, Asset, selected

    [self setImageToScrollview:_arrImages];

}

#pragma mark - Display Image to ScrollView
-(void)setImageToScrollview:(NSMutableArray *)arrSetImage

{
    // Remove all images from ScrollView and then add new one

    for(id sender in _scrImageDisplay.subviews)

        [sender removeFromSuperview];

    _scrImageDisplay.pagingEnabled = FALSE;

    CGFloat height_width = CGRectGetHeight(_scrImageDisplay.frame);

    NSInteger numberOfImages = arrSetImage.count;


    NSLog(@"Size of array is %ld",(long)numberOfImages);

    CGFloat xOrigin = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfImages ; i++)

    {
        xOrigin += 3;

        CGRect rect =  CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0,height_width,height_width);

        UIImageView *Arrimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

        Arrimage.image = [[arrSetImage objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"mainImage"];

        NSLog(@"Image data is %@",Arrimage);

        Arrimage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

        Arrimage.clipsToBounds = YES;

        [_scrImageDisplay addSubview:Arrimage];

        xOrigin += height_width;

    }

    _scrImageDisplay.contentSize = CGSizeMake(xOrigin, height_width);
}
```

Comment: It seems that the line `UIImage *image = [self.arrImages objectAtIndex:imagecount];`  is causing the issue. Could you check that's the case? If yes, `[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:imagecount];` is a `NSDictionary`, not a `UIImage` object. Could you log `[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:imagecount];`?

Comment: actually i also think so that this line is causing issue, arrImages contain all the images in it. @Larme

Comment: Log `[self.arrImages objectAtIndex:imagecount];`, that's a `NSDictionary`. I don't know how you populated `self.arrImages`, but that should be the issue.

Comment: When i log this line [self.arrImages objectAtIndex:imagecount]; its gives this in output,  TTT {
    assest = "<PHAsset: 0x7fb6ccc40540> 1D4F7544-C622-4DED-BBB3-079290A2D5A4/L0/001 mediaType=1/0, sourceType=1, (300x168), creationDate=2017-06-30 06:23:58 +0000, location=0, hidden=0, favorite=0 ";
    mainImage = "<UIImage: 0x600000284bf0>, {1000, 560}";
    selected = 1;
}
. @Larme

Comment: How did you populated `self.arrImages`. I'm not familiar with `Photos.framework`, but it seems that you didn't put an UIImage, but a PHAsset.

Comment: I have added my image selection code check it out. @Larme

Comment: Have u checked it ? @Larme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **NSURLSession** to perform image upload task. Here is the code.

```
NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type": @"application/json",
                           @"cache-control": @"no-cache",
                           };
NSDictionary *parameters = @[ @{ @"image": @“BASE_64_STRING”, @"proeprty_id": @"1", @"name": @"asd.png" } ];

NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:YOUR_SERIVCE_URL]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:10.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                if (error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                } else {
                                                    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);
                                                }
                                            }];
[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: what if i want to store the coming name of image in a variable and pass it to the parameter of name?

Comment: You can put as many para as you wan to send on server in parameters Dic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) @Nirmalsinh